# php file referencing issue on server

Tags: php

Ok, so I read several questions and answers and none of them is working for me, so here it goes:

Firstly,

1. My webhost doesn't allow: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
2. All files are supposed to be uploaded under a folder called public_html - so it's http://mysite.com/pulic_html/myfolder/myfile.php

Now my issue is -

I have a master file - init.php under http://mysite.com/pulic_html/
and I have error files under - http://mysite.com/pulic_html/pages/error/403.php

How to I include init.php in 403.php.

- edit * Please note, public_html is not a part of the URL. I have shown it here to just show where my files actually exist.

These fail:

init.php
/init.php
./init.php
../init.php

Comment: `init.php` is two folders up from `403.php`, so you'll need to go up two folders: `../../init.php`.

Comment: You are really sure that ''public_html` should be part of the url? I doubt that: usually that is just the name of the "web documents folder" inside a users home directory on a unix like system. But the http request to access documents stored there usually looks different...

Comment: public_html is not a part of the URL. I put it in there to show where my files actually exist. The files will actually be loaded as http://mysite.com/pages/error/403.php

Comment: Thanks @Vulcan. That did do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for include init.php

```
../../init.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Change webhost or switch to plan where PHP has a sensible configuration.

`public_html` should never be enforced as part of the external URL.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should be allowed, it's a read-only variable.

Comment: I know. That'd come later. But as of now, since I just need a free webhost, and frankly, these guys have a good service and support team, so will stick to them for development purposes.

Comment: If you're just doing development and you're not particularly picky, install _wampserver_ on your own (Windows) machine and develop on that. It's one of those packages where you just click 'install' and it sets defaults that aren't too bad.

Comment: Yes, I'm using XAMPP. The development so far is going fine and localhost is working great. I'm just trying to put up the placeholder page on my site to start gathering emails for when I actually take the site online.

Comment: good service would incldue NOT enforcing arbitrary/stupid sub-directories in your public-facing URL-space. They could require you to put http-related files into a public_html sub directory, but enforcing that directory being part of the URLs is just outright stupid.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. That is just a directory and not a part of the url. I put it in the question to give an idea about where my files actually exist. I'll edit the question.